# Swift - getting back to view that is not in the hierarchy

Tags: swift, hierarchy, uistoryboardsegue

I have a splash page that checks if the user is already logged in. If so, they go straight to a content page. If not, they go to the login page. My problem happens when a user who was automatically logged in tries to log out - I'd like to send them to the login page, however, they never had to visit that page so it's not in the view hierarchy. I could send them to the splash page and redirect to the login page based on a logged-out flag but that seems more like a work-around than a solution. My question: is there a way to get to a view without creating a segue from each view that has a sign out button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the LoginVC a storyboard identifier in IB and inside the logout action

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVCID")
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = vc
```

BTW you don't have to use segues , you can arbitrary navigate from a vc to another given it's identifier with present / push ( used with navigation controller )

**A memory management tip**

> Don't leave a vc in stack if you won't navigate back to